# How to check if certain words is contained by an argument or not

Tags: linux, bash, arguments

I run my script like

```
./test.sh -c "red blue yellow"
./test.sh -c "red blue"
```

And in the bash, the variable "collor" will be assigned by "red blue yellow" or "red blue"

```
echo $collor
red blue yellow
```

Two questions:

A: "red" is an important parameter for me, how can I know if red is contained in vairable color ?

```
if [ red is in color] ; then "my operation"
```

B: I have a color list with only 3 colors, how can I check if there is non-defined color passed to the script

```
./test.sh -c "red green yellow"
```

How can i define the color list and how can I do the check so that I will get the prints

```
Warnings: wrong color is green is passed to script
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(A) can be handled somewhat using wildcard string comparison:

```
if [[ "$color" = *red* ]]; then
    echo 'I am the Red Queen!'
elif [[ "$color" = *white* ]]; then
    echo 'I am the White Queen!'
fi
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not handle word boundaries very well (or at all); `red` will trigger the first condition, but so will `orange-red` and `bored`. In addition, (B) will be hard (or impossible) to implement in this manner.

The best way to deal with this would be to assign the color list to a [Bash array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

```
COLORS=($color)

for i in "${COLORS[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$i" = "red" ]]; then
        echo 'I am the Red Queen!'
    elif [[ "$i" = "white" ]]; then
        echo 'I am the White Queen!'
    fi
done
```

You can then use a nested loop to iterate over another array that contains the allowed colors and report any input color that is not found there.

Answer (score 0):

> A: "red" is an important parameter for me, how can I know if red is
>   contained in vairable color?

You could say:

```
if [[ "$2" == *red* ]]; then
  echo "Color red is present ..."
fi
```

The condition would be true only if the color `red` was included in the arguments to the script (`./test.sh -c "red blue yellow"`).

> B: I have a color list with only 3 colors, how can I check if there is
>   non-defined color passed to the script

```
colors=(red blue yellow)       # color list with three colors
IFS=$' ' read -a foo <<< "$2"
echo "${#foo[@]}"
for color in "${foo[@]}"; do
  if [[ "${colors[@]}" != *${color}* ]]; then
    echo incorrect color $color
  fi
done
```